# Filter OData always returns all entries

Tags: odata

I have an OData Feed from an REST API. I want to filter the entries of a collection to get just one specific entry. But it always returns me all entries.
I tried this GET Statement:
https://apiurl/Belege?$filter=Belegnummer eq '23000001'

And the answer looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://apiurl/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/</id>
    <title />
    <updated>2023-12-12T14:00:37Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" href="https://apiurl/Belege" />
    <entry>
        <id>https://apiurl/Belege(614105)</id>
        <category term="Api.Models.Belege" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="https://apiurl/Belege(614105)" />
        <link rel="self" href="https://apiurl/Belege(614105)" />
        <title />
        <updated>2023-12-12T14:00:37Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PK_BelegID m:type="Edm.Int32">614105</d:PK_BelegID>
                <d:Belegstatus>verarbeitet</d:Belegstatus>
                <d:FK_BetriebsstaetteID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:FK_BetriebsstaetteID>
                <d:FK_ProjektID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FK_ProjektID>
                <d:BelegartBeschreibung>Rechnung</d:BelegartBeschreibung>
                <d:BelegartKurz>SL</d:BelegartKurz>
                <d:FK_VerkaufsbelegartID m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:FK_VerkaufsbelegartID>
                <d:Belegnummer>23000001</d:Belegnummer>
                ...
```

I really don't know what else to do. I always get all 614105 entries in return.

**UPDATE:**
https://apiurl/Belege/$metadata returns an invalid path.
But https://apiurl/$metadata returns this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <Schema Namespace="MyAPI" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
            <EntityContainer Name="MyAPIService" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="Belege" EntityType="MyAPI.Models.Belege" />
                ...
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="MyAPI.Models" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
            <EntityType Name="Belege">
                <Documentation>
                    <Summary>alle Belege mit definierten Filtern/Datensatzberechtigungen</Summary>
                    <LongDescription></LongDescription>
                </Documentation>
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="PK_BelegID" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="PK_BelegID" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="Belegnummer" Type="Edm.String" />
                ...
```

**Update 2:**
$top does work. When I try $select I get following error message:
*'EdmEntityObjectCollection' cannot be serialized using the ODataMediaTypeFormatter.*

Comment: What is the version of OData supported by the service and if >=2, does it support filtering?

Comment: Unfortunately there is nearly no documentation at all. So I don't know which version it is. All i could find is this statement:
"In an external application, this URL can be used to access the REST API via which the data is retrieved and imported into the application. The REST interface is accessed via the OData protocol (= OpenData protocol), which is used for HTTP-based data exchange between two software systems."
Normally it is used for Microsoft PowerBI but I need it in a PHP application

Comment: What does `https://apiurl/Belege/$metadata` return?

Comment: Please see my update above

Comment: Can you use &$top=1 ?
And maybe use a $select too for specific fields

Comment: We have an intern API running using OData v4. We send requests to: apiurl/api/odata/Article for example.

Network tab says:
odata.context:"https://apiurl/api/odata/$metadata#Article

Comment: This seems to be an OData v3 but filtering may have been disabled, do you have documentation for this API?

Comment: That's the problem. There is no documentation. Maybe I'm lucky and I can get support from the api developers.
Thanks for your help though.